# Visual Studio 2013 for web : replacing all the LF with CRLF

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Im using Visual Studio 2013 for my project + I use git to save each step.

git is awesome, but it has this annoying habit to change my files without my permission.
I've tried the 2 options : 'windows style' and 'as-is', no matter what git keeps changing my files.

I had no problemes with that, but since 'intellisense' stopped working for some of my files i need to fix it. Its random, and it depends if I commit to git or not.

Here is my question: how in VS2013 (for web) I can fix all the CRLF/LF issues? (without installing any plugin if possible).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `.gitattributes` file in your project? If so, what is the

```
* text=[some value here]
```

line set to?

Also, do you override any files to use specific line endings? For example, I can force my Mac to download git-controlled files with CRLF (instead of LF) with these settings:

```
* text=auto
*.cs        eol=crlf
*.sln       eol=crlf
*.csproj    eol=crlf
```

Then, within Visual Studio itself, I can Save As... the files and ensure that the files end in CRLF.

Answer (score 0):

Before posting this question i didnt know that i can commit to git using VS.

here is a link to do so http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/share-your-code-in-git-vs

OnlineCop's answer is also correct, but VS automatically adds his own attributes to git.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Post follow-up questions here if you need more help!